# Finding contiguous ranges in arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

You are given an array of integers. You have to output the largest range so that all numbers in the range are present in the array. The numbers might be present in any order.  For example, suppose that the array is

```
{2, 10, 3, 12, 5, 4, 11, 8, 7, 6, 15}
```

Here we find two (nontrivial) ranges for which all the integers in these ranges are present in the array, namely [2,8] and [10,12].  Out of these [2,8] is the longer one. So we need to output that.

When I was given this question, I was asked to do this in linear time and without using any sorting.  I thought that there might be a hash-based solution, but I couldn't come up with anything.

Here's my attempt at a solution:

```
void printRange(int arr[])
{
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int size=2;
    int tempans[2]; 

    int answer[2];// the range is stored in another array
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[0]<arr[1])
        {
             answer[0]=arr[0];
             answer[1]=arr[1];
        }
        if(arr[1]<arr[0])
        {
            answer[0]=arr[1];
            answer[1]=arr[0];
        }

        if(arr[i] < answer[1])
            size += 1;
        else if(arr[i]>answer[1]) {
            initialize tempans to new range;
             size2=2;
        }
        else { 
            initialize tempans  to new range
        }
}

//I have to check when the count becomes equal to the diff of the range
```

I am stuck at this part... I can't figure out how many tempanswer[] arrays should be  used.

Comment: The way the question is worded is a bit confusing, though I understand it now.  You want to find the largest set of contiguous numbers in the array.  In your example, `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8` are values in the array, but `1 and 9` aren't, so one of your candidate results is `[2 - 8]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the following solution will work in O(n) time using O(n) space.

Begin by putting all of the entries in the array into a hash table.  Next, create a second hash table which stores elements that we have "visited," which is initially empty.

Now, iterate across the array of elements one at a time.  For each element, check if the element is in the visited set.  If so, skip it.  Otherwise, count up from that element upward.  At each step, check if the current number is in the main hash table.  If so, continue onward and mark the current value as part of the visited set.  If not, stop.  Next, repeat this procedure, except counting downward.  This tells us the number of contiguous elements in the range containing this particular array value.  If we keep track of the largest range found this way, we will have a solution to our problem.

The runtime complexity of this algorithm is O(n).  To see this, note that we can build the hash table in the first step in O(n) time.  Next, when we begin scanning to array to find the largest range, each range scanned takes time proportional to the length of that range.  Since the total sum of the lengths of the ranges is the number of elements in the original array, and since we never scan the same range twice (because we mark each number that we visit), this second step takes O(n) time as well, for a net runtime of O(n).

**EDIT:** If you're curious, I have a **[Java implementation](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=longest-range)** of this algorithm, along with a much more detailed analysis of why it works and why it has the correct runtime.  It also explores a few edge cases that aren't apparent in the initial description of the algorithm (for example, how to handle integer overflow).

Hope this helps!

Comment: But in worst case even "check if the element is in the visited set" takes O(n) for every single element (if all elements are mapped to the same hash). Moreover given any hash function this check will never be better than some w(1) (litte omega) in worst case, therefore the overall algorithm does not seem to be O(n). Am i missing something?

Comment: @dcn- if you use a dynamic perfect hash table or a cuckoo hash table, then any hash lookup is worst-case O(1), so you don't need to worry about lookups taking O(n).  Also, you are correct that hash insertion can degrade to worse than O(1), but with either of the aforementioned hash systems the probability of this occurring is exponentially small; IIRC the probability of the runtime of n inserts into a dynamic perfect hash table being greater than kn for any constant k is 1/2^k, so the chances of this being much slower than linear is extremely small.

Comment: So what about when the input is {0,9000000000000,1000000000000,8000000000000}?

Comment: @greim- In that case, the algorithm returns a range of length 1, since there are no two consecutive numbers.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. But can't this be done by combining both the hashtables into one?

Comment: @Maverickgugu Almost certainly. :-) I answered this almost literally five years ago to the date, and I suspect that this could be significantly cleaned up.

Answer (score 8):

The solution could use `BitSet`:

```
public static void detect(int []ns) {
    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < ns.length; i++) {
        bs.set(ns[i]);
    }
    int begin = 0;
    int setpos = -1;
    while((setpos = bs.nextSetBit(begin)) >= 0) {
        begin = bs.nextClearBit(setpos);
        System.out.print("[" + setpos + " , " + (begin - 1) + "]");
    }
}
```

Sample I/O:

```
detect(new int[] {2,10, 3, 12, 5,4, 11, 8, 7, 6, 15} );
```

```
[2,8] [10,12] [15,15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in Java:

```
public class Solution {  
    public int longestConsecutive(int[] num) {  
        int longest = 0;  
        Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();  
        for(int i = 0; i< num.length; i++){  
            map.put(num[i], false);  
        }  

        int l, k;  
        for(int i = 0;i < num.length;i++){  

            if(map.containsKey(num[i]-1) || map.get(num[i])) continue;  
            map.put(num[i], true);  
            l = 0; k = num[i];  
            while (map.containsKey(k)){  
                l++;  
                k++;  
            }  
            if(longest < l) longest = l;  

        }  
        return longest;  
    }  
}
```

Other approaches [here](http://traceformula.blogspot.com/2015/07/longest-consecutive-sequence-some.html).

Comment: can we optimize this algorithm by doing this : 
like when we traverse to find (map.containsKey(k)), we also use another loop where we decrement k, in that way we can find both left and right side continuous no's and plus we can set them to true so that we don't have to traverse again.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by template will work but you don't need a hash table. Hashing *could* take a long time depending on what algorithm you use. You can ask the interviewer if there's a max number the integer can be, then create an array of that size. Call it exist[] Then scan through arr and mark exist[i] = 1; Then iterate through exist[] keeping track of 4 variables, size of current largest range, and the beginning of the current largest range, size of current range, and beginning of current range. When you see exist[i] = 0, compare the current range values vs largest range values and update the largest range values if needed.

If there's no max value then you might have to go with the hashing method.

Comment: I think the best it can get is O(maxValue - minValue). I don't see how could this be O(n). (Unless that IS O(n), but I always understood O(n) is proportional to the size of the array.

Comment: If you use a hash system like dynamic perfect hashing or cuckoo hashing, then with very high probability the runtime will be O(n) for n hash inserts, and you can guarantee worst-case O(1) lookup times.

Answer (score 0):

Actually considering that we're only sorting integers and therefore a comparision sort is NOT necessary, you can just sort the array using a Radix- or BucketSort and then iterate through it.

Simple and certainly not what the interviewee wanted to hear, but correct nonetheless ;)

Comment: Sorting will not happen in O(n) though

Comment: @user1767754 Radix sort is very much O(N) for fixed size integers. If we aren't dealing with fixed size integers none of the other solutions will be O(N) either as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

A Haskell implementation of Grigor Gevorgyan's solution, from another who didn't get a chance to post before the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591467/find-the-biggest-interval-that-has-all-its-members-in-list-in-on) was marked as a duplicate...(simply updates the hash and the longest range so far, while traversing the list)

```
import qualified Data.HashTable.IO as H
import Control.Monad.Random

f list = do 
  h <- H.new :: IO (H.BasicHashTable Int Int)
  g list (0,[]) h where
    g []     best h = return best
    g (x:xs) best h = do 
      m <- H.lookup h x
      case m of
        Just _     -> g xs best h
        otherwise  -> do 
          (xValue,newRange) <- test
          H.insert h x xValue
          g xs (maximum [best,newRange]) h
       where 
         test = do
           m1 <- H.lookup h (x-1)
           m2 <- H.lookup h (x+1)
           case m1 of
             Just x1 -> case m2 of
                          Just x2 -> do H.insert h (x-1) x2
                                        H.insert h (x+1) x1
                                        return (x,(x2 - x1 + 1,[x1,x2]))
                          Nothing -> do H.insert h (x-1) x
                                        return (x1,(x - x1 + 1,[x,x1]))
             Nothing -> case m2 of
                          Just x2 -> do H.insert h (x+1) x
                                        return (x2,(x2 - x + 1,[x,x2]))
                          Nothing -> do return (x,(1,[x]))

rnd :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Int
rnd = getRandomR (-100,100)

main = do
  values <- evalRandIO (sequence (replicate (1000000) rnd))
  f values >>= print
```

Output:

```
*Main> main
(10,[40,49])
(5.30 secs, 1132898932 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot of solutions on multiple platforms to this problem and one got my attention, as it solves the problem very elegantly and it is easy to follow.

The backbone of this method is to create a set/hash which takes O(n) time and from there every access to the set/hash will be O(1). As the O-Notation omit's constant terms, this Algorithm still can be described overall as  `O(n)`

```
def longestConsecutive(self, nums):
    nums = set(nums)                    # Create Hash O(1)   
    best = 0
    for x in nums:                   
        if x - 1 not in nums:           # Optimization
            y = x + 1                   # Get possible next number
            while y in nums:            # If the next number is in set/hash
                y += 1                  # keep counting
            best = max(best, y - x)     # counting done, update best
    return best
```

It's straight forward if you ran over it with simple numbers. The `Optimization` step is just a short-circuit to make sure you start counting, when that specific number is the `beginning` of a sequence.

All Credits to Stefan Pochmann.

Answer (score 0):

Very short solution using Javascript sparse array feature:

O(n) time using O(n) additional space.

```
var arr = [2, 10, 3, 12, 5, 4, 11, 8, 7, 6, 15];

var a = [];
var count = 0, max_count = 0;

for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) a[arr[i]] = true;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    count = (a[i]) ? count + 1 : 0;
    max_count = Math.max(max_count, count);
    }

console.log(max_count); // 7
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick way to do it (PHP) :

```
$tab = array(14,12,1,5,7,3,4,10,11,8);
asort($tab);
$tab = array_values($tab);
$tab_contiguous = array();
$i=0;
foreach ($tab as $key => $val) {
    $tab_contiguous[$i][] = $tab[$key];
    if (isset($tab[$key+1])) {
        if($tab[$key] + 1 != $tab[$key+1])
            $i++;
    }
}
echo(json_encode($tab_contiguous));
```