# Elementary Mutable Haskell Hash Table

Tags: haskell

Experimenting with a simple hash table [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415305/finding-contiguous-ranges-in-arrays/17605178#17605178), seemed to work for me using Data.HashMap. I am hoping to understand better how to implement a mutable hash table (would this be Data.HashTable.IO?) that would allow for faster performance. I am totally lost...tried to modify the example [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashtables/1.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-HashTable-IO.html) but could not find my way through the IO types I got in return (pun intended)...thanks in advance for any kind walk-through or reference to one.

For example, how to implement this simple exercise using a mutable hash table?

```
import qualified Data.HashMap as HM (toList,lookup,insert,empty)

f list = g list HM.empty where
  g []     h = HM.toList h
  g (x:xs) h = case HM.lookup (x-1) h of
                 Just _  -> g xs (HM.insert x (x + 1) h)
                 Nothing -> g xs (HM.insert x x h)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type signature for `HM.insert` is

`insert :: IOHashTable h k v -> k -> v -> IO ()`

From this signature we can see that `insert` doesn't return a new hashmap with the element inserted, it is actually an `IO` action that does the inserting for us, mutating the old hashmap in place.

Similarly, `HM.lookup` returns its result in the `IO` monad too:

`lookup :: IOHashTable h k v -> k -> IO (Maybe v)`

So we'll need to do some work binding the `IO` actions these functions return. I think you want something like this.

```
f xs = g xs HM.empty
    where g [] h     = HM.toList h
          g (x:xs) h = do
              res <- HM.lookup (x-1) h
              case res of
                  Nothing -> HM.insert h x x
                  Just _  -> HM.insert h x (x+1)
              g xs h
```

Comment: Thanks! That got me passed the case/lookup hurdle (...there seem to be a few more things to workout, though, like `new` rather than `empty`...and how to show IO types, like `IO [(k0, v0)]`, which is the result of `toList`?)

Comment: if you have a `x :: IO a`, you can use `x >>= print` to show it

Comment: @groovy which is, by the way, merely a more expressive way of saying `\list <- x; print list`

Comment: @JustinL. you mean `do { a <- x; print a }`? Hopefully thats not some lambda syntax language extension I'm unaware of.

Comment: @ChrisDueck yes I do, not sure how that slash crept in there heh